# ¿Como usar variable de un component en src de etiqueta audio en Angular 2?

Tags: html5, firebase, angularjs-2.0, typescript

hola a todos y gracias de antemano, estoy generando la URL de un archivo de audio en Firebase y quiero usarlo en el src de la etiqueta audio. ya probé con {{*variable*}} en la variable y [*src*] en src (obviamente no usándolas al mismo tiempo)pero hasta ahora no consigo un buen resultado.

Perdón si parece una tontería(para ustedes tal vez lo sea)pero estoy iniciando desde hace un mes en Angular2 y no entiendo bien esa parte, no se si estoy omitiendo algo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<audio controls src={{filetoplay}}></audio>
```

filetoplay es un string declarado en el componente que contiene la URL.